# Calculate distance between points in matrix connected in all directions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, matrix, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to make an online game where I want to simulate a world that is connected in all directions, just like "PAC-MAN" does. When the player crosses the boundaries of the map he would be in the other side of the grid.

So far so good, I managed to build a server that holds a 10x10 matrix, (I attach some [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5BvG.png) as a reference), and using some modular-arithmetics it calculates and sends to the client the corresponding tiles of the map given the player's position.

So assuming "view_distance = 2" for example, the server sends the corresponding tiles based on the player's position:

[Player position (4,4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0WoK.png)

[Player position (9,5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVCsH.png)

[Player position (0,0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXnOq.png)

I think I made my point, now lets face my problem.

When the client gets the list of tiles to render from the server, it needs to calculate the distance to the player (unit-vector) for each tile so it can instance it in the right place. Every instanced tile has a script that recalculates the distance to the player every time he moves so it destroys itself when it is farther than the "view_distance".

So for example, if I the client is in the position (9,5) the unit-vector of the tile (7,7) would be (-2,2)

The client has the following information:

- The tile where he's standing:  `Globals.PlayerInfo.PlayerPosition`
- The lenght of the map:  `Globals.MAP_LENGHT` (in this case it's 10)
- The view distance:  `Globals.DATA_DISTANCE` (in this case it's 2)

How do i calculate the unit-vector? I made the following function but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

```
public static Position GetPlayerDistance(Position position)
    {
        var unitVector = new Position() { X = position.X, Y = position.Y };
        if (position.Y > Math.Truncate(Globals.PlayerInfo.PlayerPosition.Y) + Globals.DATA_DISTANCE)
        {
            unitVector.Y = position.Y - Globals.MAP_LENGHT;
        }

        if (position.X > Math.Truncate(Globals.PlayerInfo.PlayerPosition.X) + Globals.DATA_DISTANCE)
        {
            unitVector.X = position.X - Globals.MAP_LENGHT;
        }
        unitVector.X -= (float)Math.Truncate(Globals.PlayerInfo.PlayerPosition.X);
        unitVector.Y -= (float)Math.Truncate(Globals.PlayerInfo.PlayerPosition.Y);

        return unitVector;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say it yourself, the grid is `connected in all directions`. So since your grid is "infinite" every position exists an "infinite" amount of times. What you are looking for is not one distance between two points but actually the smallest one out of multiple possibilities.

No worries, though ;) It is fully enough to check once into each direction (up, down, left, right) and chose the smallest of the resulting distances in these direction since any other one will be further away anyways.

As only one example what I am talking about.
Lets say

- the player is at `1,1` (red)
- the enemy is at `8,2` (blue)

so if we want to get the minimum distance on the X axis we simply check in both directions, to the left and to the right.

In this case finding the next position to the left is trivial: It is the actual player position `x = 1`.

Now what do we to towards the right? → We simply virtually extend the grid (light-grey) and map the player position to where it **would** be in that extended grid → `x = 11` (light-red).

Here is an image to visualize it better

[image]

In the code this might look like e.g.

```
public static Position GetPlayerDistance(Position position)
{
    // Get values local to not go through the accessors all the time
    Position playerPos = Globals.PlayerInfo.PlayerPosition;
    int playerX = (int)playerPos.X;
    int playerY = (int)playerPos.Y;

    int ownX = (int)position.X;
    int ownY = (int)position.Y;

    // On the X axis gather the next actual or virtual player position
    // where virtual means as if the grid was extended

    // Per default assume the positions are equal  
    var nextXLeft = ownX;
    var nextXRight = ownX;

    // Is the player actually left of us?
    if(playerX < ownX)
    {
        // Then trivial: the next left position is the actual one
        nextXLeft = playerX;
        // The next right position is a virtual one so we pretend
        // to extend the grid by the length and "copy" the player there
        nextXRight = Globals.MAP_LENGHT + playerX;
    } 
    // Or is the player actually right of us?
    else if (playerX > ownX)
    {
        // Just the other way round
        // this time the next position to the left is virtual
        nextXLeft = -Globals.MAP_LENGHT + playerX;
        // The next right position is the actual one
        nextXRight = playerX;
    }

    // Now we calculate the directed distances in both directions
    var distanceLeft = nextXLeft - ownX;
    var distanceRight = nextXRight - ownX;

    // use the Absolute only for comparing which is shorter
    var distanceX = Mathf.Abs(distanceRight) < Mathf.Abs(distanceLeft) ? distanceRight : distanceLeft;

    // And finally we want the smallest of both possible distances
    var distanceX = Mathf.Min(distanceLeft, distanceRight);

    // Repeat the same for the Y axis
    var nextYDown = ownY;
    var nextYUp = ownY;
    if(playerY < ownY)
    {
        nextYDown = playerY;
        nextYUp = Globals.MAP_LENGHT + playerY;
    } 
    else if (playerY > ownY)
    {
        nextYDown = -Globals.MAP_LENGHT + playerY;
        nextYUp = playerY;
    }

    var distanceDown = nextYDown - ownY;
    var distanceUp = nextYUp - ownY;

    var distanceY = Mathf.Abs(distanceUp) < Mathf.Abs(distanceDown) ? distanceUp : distanceDown;

    // Now you have a directed distance vector for both axis with the 
    // minimal absolute distance from the player
    return new Position(){ X = distanceX, Y = distanceY };
}
```

---

Here is a little visualization of how it works now

[image]

---

As a side note: There is already [`Vector2Int`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2Int.html) you might want to use instead of your custom `Position`

Comment: I need to know the direction. If I use your code, if the player is in the position (0,0) the outctome of your function for the tile (8,8) would be (2,2), but i need it to be (-2, -2).
Thank you for taking the time to look on my problem, i really appreaciate it :)

Comment: @blacksmith see my little Update at the bottom ;) I wasn't sure about the sign of the direction .. so you might have to change the order from `ownX - nextXLeft` etc to `nextXLeft - ownX` depending in which direction the resulting vector should point

Comment: Thanks for the update! I tried your code, but if the position of the player is (0,8) the outcome for the tile (8,0) is (-2,-8), and it should be (-2, 2).

Comment: oh there was a copy-paste typo sorry ^^ in the `else if (playerY > ownY)` it should ofcourse be using the `playerY`, not the `playerX` ;)

Comment: I think its working! Now I have another bug but I think it has nothing to do with this problem. You have my upvote sir :)